# If I send 4mbps of data to a friend with 4mbps connection, will I DoS him?

Tags: attacks, attack-prevention, denial-of-service

Suppose my friend has a connection of 4mbps. If I just send him 4mpbs of random data with my server, wouldn't it block his connection? Even if the router has firewalls and closed ports, isn't enough for me to send random data continuosly to his router, in order to block it?

I've found some scripts on the internet (like [this](http://skidpaste.org/SersZQbI)) and I tried to block my own connection with my server, but nothing happened.

Comment: Also, please note that it's only denial of service if it's for a malicious purpose. If the data you're sending is normal usage of a service/app he's hosting then there is no DoS/DDoS involved. Saturating a connection doesn't magically turn it into a DoS attack.

Comment: This is plain DoS, not **D**DoS (*Distributed* DoS).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're just throwing data at a closed port, your friend will notice a substantial slowdown in his Internet connectivity and an increase in packet loss, but it will not result in an inability to use the Internet.

Think of his connection as a pipe: you're trying to throw 4Mbps down a 4Mbps pipe, and he's trying to pull additional data down.  Something has to give, and it happens in the form of dropped packets.  The packets to drop are selected randomly, and since most of the packets are your attack packets, they will also constitute most of the dropped packets.  Packets he wants will get through often enough for the connection to be somewhat usable.

In order to perform a bandwidth-starvation attack of the sort you're describing, you need to throw far more data than the target can handle, so that almost all of the data the target wants gets dropped.

(Terminology note: this is a DoS, not a Distributed DoS, since you're only attacking from one location.)

Answer (score 3):

You are probably not sending 4Mbps of data with that script, because that script tries a TCP connection on port 80. It will of course fail as you haven't got a web server running, so it will be difficult for your server to reach those sustained 4Mbps of traffic towards your home connection.

That script will be sending SYN packets and waiting for a SYN ACK before timing out, introducing delays on your flood. Even being a multi-threaded attack won't do much as you've already seen.

Common DDoS attacks use UDP to just flood the target. UDP doesn't wait for acknowledgements, just *fires and forgets* hence making it easier to flood someone that's not running any publicly reachable services.

Also, for the sake of completion (as it's already been pointed on a different answer) you're not *DDoSing* anyone if the attack is started from one host. The first D in DDoS means "Distributed".

Finally you are almost right on your initial assumption. Technically, you would just need the same amount of bandwidth than your target to make their life miserable.